# Android Media Player - start called in state 1

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

```
player.reset();
player.setDataSource(url);
// mPlayer.setDataSource(mFileName);
player.prepareAsync();
player.setOnPreparedListener(
     new OnPreparedListener() {
         @Override
         public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
             player.start();
         }
     }
);
```

This is my mediaplayer bit code. I'm doing the exact thing I should be doing in order to have the state of the media player correctly yet I'm still having the error `start called in state 1` can anyone help? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is  is possible to share your stacktrace?

Comment: Is the `OnPreparedListener` the only place you're calling `start()`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the problem here is that you need to set the listener before you call `player.prepareAsync();` because there is always the possibility (especially if the url points to the disk) that the `prepareAsync` call might return before the listener is set.

Answer (score 6):

Change `player.start();` to `mp.start();`